# Where in Mage Core is a product's status set?

Tags: magento, status, extend, mage

I'm trying to extend the core to change how magento sets the status on products. Essentially, when an admin user tries to change the status of a product to disabled, I want it to check to see if the product is in stock in their EPOS system, and if it is, throw an error.

To do this, I was going to extend the model where the product status is set and rewrite that function. The problem is, I can't find this anywhere. There is nothing in magento_core_model_product. I found a function in mage_catalog_model_product_status called updateProductStatus, but this doesn't seem right either.

Does anybody know where I need to be looking to find this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found that Magento generates all the getters and setters pragmatically, through extensive use of the `__call()` function, which is called when a function that isn't defined is called.

To modify functionality of a getter or setter, simply define the function you want to modify in your rewrite of the class, and this will be called before the `__call()`, essentially rewriting the default functionality, in a roundabout way.

Comment: Another way is to [observe the event](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) `catalog_product_save_before`. If the status value hasn't changed but the EPOS status has this gives you an extra opportunity to correct the difference.

Comment: That's a much simpler solution. I wish I thought of that a day ago. Thanks for the suggestion. As a rule of thumb, is it better to use events over extending core objects where possible?

Comment: Yes events are preferable. Several different listeners can observe an event at once (perhaps separate modules from unrelated developers) without interfering with each other. But only one can extend a core object at once, any other module must then override the override which is needlessly complex.